# How do I use a c++ array with int 0 and '\0'

Tags: c++, arrays

I am using a c++ integer array (int *). I have number sets generated and placed into this array, such as `1, 0, 3, 4, 5`. The array is allotted 16 characters by this method

```
int *arr = (int *)malloc(16).
```

I need to be able to loop through this array and use each number and tell how many numbers are in the array. To loop through each element in the array, I have tried two methods:

```
for(int i=0;i<sizeof(arr);i++) and for(int i=0;arr[i]!='\0';i++).
```

The problem with the first method is that `sizeof` returns `16`, because thats how much space I allotted for that array. The second method is successful unless there is a `0` in the sequence. How should I go about looping through each element in the array without getting stuck on `0` or looping through all `16` slots?

Comment: `int*` is not an array. It is a pointer. `The problem with the first method is that sizeof returns 16` No it doesn't.

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? Instantiating an array of `int` and looping over it really isn't that complicated.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit how? That creates a usable array for me. Thats what I though at first too but it created an array for me. That method that I said above seemed to work the same way as int arr[16];

Comment: The problem is that you didn't study pointers and arrays thoroughly enough, and/or you didn't think about the problem using your programming knowledge, logic and common sense. You will need to read a good beginner C++ book or tutorial, especially its chapter(s) that cover(s) pointers and arrays.

Comment: Are you sure `sizeof(arr)` is giving `16`? I'd think it would be 4 or 8, usually, on account of `arr` being a pointer. Also, you're confusing "integer slots" with bytes -- 16 bytes only gives you four integers' worth of slots, assuming 4-byte integers.

Comment: @InsertNameHere: What do you mean "how?" `int*` is a pointer, I just told you. You didn't create any array but simply allocated a block of contiguous `int`s in dynamic memory. An array is like `int arr[16]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you've used dynamic allocation for this "array" (block of memory), the dimension of the array is not known to the type system. That means you *cannot* use `sizeof(arr)`. All you've done there is find the size of your `int*` (a pointer).

And, as you've discovered, trying to null-terminate this array is completely silly because `0` is a perfectly valid, sane integer value.

What you *should* do is one of the following:

#### Option 1

```
const unsigned int LENGTH = 16;
int* ptr = new int[LENGTH];     // (malloc is an ancient approach from C)

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++) {
   // ...
}

delete[] ptr;

// here, I've remembered the block's size myself
```

#### Option 2

```
std::vector<int> vec(16);
for (auto myInt : vec) {
   // ...
}

// here, the wrapper called "vector" knows its own size
```

#### Option 2a

If you just picked `16` arbitrarily to provide a maximum upper bound, and you don't *always* need 16 elements:

```
std::vector<int> vec;   // this grows as needed
vec.push_back(1);
vec.push_back(0);
vec.push_back(3);

for (auto myInt : vec) {
   // ...
}
```

#### Option 3

If the value `16` doesn't rely on user input or other runtime data, leave out the dynamic allocation:

```
std::array<int, 16> arr;
for (auto myInt : arr) {
   // ...
}
```

Or, to go old-school:

```
int arr[16];
for (auto myInt : arr) {
   // ...
}
```

#### Conclusion

It's hard to tell what you're trying to do, but I *think* you are trying to have a bunch of array elements, not all of which may be "used" at any one time, and somehow mark the "un-used" ones. In this case, you want to abandon that old-fashioned logic, and use **option 2a** above.

#### Bootnote

I've used some C++11 constructs here, namely `std::array` and the ranged-for loop. Replace the loops with more conventional equivalents as you required.

Comment: I don't want to loop through all the elements in the array, only the ones that aren't null. Is there a way I can stop at the null ones? I want to get how many elements aren't null.

Comment: @InsertNameHere: You have to look through them all otherwise you won't know which are "null". You need to define what you mean by "null". I think you are coming from a Java background where objects can either have a value or "be null", but that is not the case here.

Comment: haha no actually I do mainly Objective C, but that is the case there as well as Java. What I mean by null is that i haven't set a value to it yet.

Comment: @InsertNameHere: Then you are trying to fill in array elements to a maximum quantity, and somehow "mark" the un-used ones. Instead of this, use my **option 2a** above which simply expands your array as necessary, leaving no "un-used" elements at all. Your only other alternative is to pick a sentinel value (say, `-1`) and stick with it.

Comment: Sorry, what exactly does a vector do? I don't quite understand your code, for I have never used vectors before. Could you explain please? @LighnessRacesInOrbit

Comment: @InsertNameHere: Now's the time to go and look it up. :) This should be covered pretty well in [your C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Thanks a lot this actually saved me loads of time.

Comment: @InsertNameHere: Good :)

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof` returns the types size in bytes, *not* the length of an array. So, to get method #1 to work, you'll have to store the length of the array.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `countof` instead of `sizeof`:

```
template <typename T, size_t N> size_t countof( T (&array)[N] ){return N;}
```

I don't know exactly why it works (I mean I don't know how to write it if I loose it) but I use it (I will try to understand it - now!)

Another method I know better how to explain is using
`sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int)`.

Avoid using "special case" values when you can. There are always causing problems.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some very good answers written but I just wanted to add an ugly one:

If you want the size of the array in the way you write it

`int *arr = (int*)malloc(16);`

the size would depend on the size of an int on your system, it could be e.g 4 bytes per int so max 4 ints would fit in. In order to keep track of the size of what you have allocated you will need to manually enter the size in the allocated block e.g.

```
int n = 4;
int *arr = (int*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(int)); 
*arr = 4;
```

then move the pointer

```
++arr;
```

whenever you need the size, check `*(arr-1)`

when you free the block make sure to use `free(arr-1)`

probably best to wrap them in some kind of function to hide the ugliness.

I *really* do not recommend this method since you are programming in C++, avoid `malloc/free` since they are not very C++ compatible, i.e. they know nothing about constructors, instead use `new/new[]/delete/delete[]` also `vector<>` is one of my favorite templates, once you know how to use that arrays will be a breeze.